# Reading/Writing files to HDFS from Windwos server

Tags: linux, windows, hadoop, hdfs

I want to write files to HDFS from windows server. Hadoop cluster is on Linux.
I tried researching everywhere I got a java code that can be run using "hadoop jar"

Can somebody help me to understand how can I run HDFS file write java code from windows? What is required on Windows box? Even a proper link will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to code a simple java program and run it like a normal .jar file.

In the project you need to import the hadoop library.

This is a working example maven project (I tested it on my cluster):

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class WriteFileToHdfs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        String dataNameLocation = "hdfs://[your-namenode-ip]:[the-port-where-hadoop-is-listening]/";

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get( new URI( dataNameLocation ), configuration );
        Path file = new Path(dataNameLocation+"/myFile.txt");

        FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(file);
        out.writeUTF("Some text ...");
        out.close();

        hdfs.close();

    }

}
```

Remember to put the dependencies to your pom.xml and the instruction to build the manifest file for the main class:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <mainClass>your.cool.package.WriteFileToHdfs</mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>            
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Just lunch the program with the command:

> java -jar nameOfTheJarFile.jar

Of course you need to edit the code with your package name and namenode ip address.

Comment: Hi Yes you are right, but I don't want to run it with "hadoop jar" command . Is it not possible to have java code interacting with HDFS which can be run with just "java" command ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I wanted to tell you :). You need only to import the hadoop libraries and then  run the progam with the java command

Comment: Thank you so much , sorry but  I'm not that good with Maven can you please explain "Remember to put the dependencies to your pom.xml" what exactly I need to put here

Comment: If you don't want to use maven just download the hadoop-library .jar (search on google) and import it into the project .

Comment: Sorry, rename "Main" with "main" ... I put capitol letter but it need only "main"

Comment: still same "Error: Could not find or load main class WriteFileToHdfs".....I copy pasted your code and added Hadoop libraries now running "javac" and "java" . am I missing something ? does this work for you ?

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma did you rename the main class as I told you ? Check the name please.

Comment: Yes I did rename it with "main"

Comment: Well, it should work. Now I'm out. Tomorrow I'll check again. Try searhing on google, it's very simple using hadoop-client api with java

Comment: It does work if I run it with "hadoop jar" not working with "java"

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma I have updated the answer. Maybe you didn't set in the pom.xml the mainClass and the instruction to generate the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you so much Simone it worked for me, now I have to add Kerberos authentication in code I have Keytab file and username can you please suggest ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know Kerberos authentication :) If the answer was  helpful please flag it as accepted and/or vote it. Thanks