# creating a file on HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create a file in hdfs and from my windows machine to test my code. for that i have followed this link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455888/reading-writing-files-to-hdfs-from-windwos-server) and it worked fine with the give code on the post as it is a maven project.

What I need is to create a dynamic web project in eclipse. What I have done is I took hadoop-client-2.6.1.jar and placed in my project but it simply comes out to finally block when it is trying for the line below

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.set("fs.defaultFS",hdfsUri );
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(sHdfsLandOutPath), configuration);
            Path file = new Path(sHdfsLandOutPath + sTableName + ".txt");
```

I don't understand what is the issue as it doesn't throw any error when i ran it from windows machine whereas when i run it through linux, i get the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Interners
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringInterner.<clinit>(StringInterner.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1918)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1093)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:363)
        at com.jms.demo.JMSConsumer.runConsumer(JMSConsumer.java:115)
        at com.jms.demo.JMSConsumer.main(JMSConsumer.java:79)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Interners
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: @Simone Pessotto Would need your inputs here. can you please tell me which all jars i need to download from maven directly as mine is not a maven project.. links to the all the jars required would be really helpful.. thanks it bit critical and urgent for me.

Comment: i have copied jars from this link https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.6.5/source-code but even then code exits from  line "  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(sHdfsLandOutPath), configuration);" i am not sure why this is happening .. can any expert help me find the RCA of this issue.

Comment: You need a lot more than a single JAR file... Why not just add Maven or Gradle to your project so that'll put Hadoop clients into your web app?

Comment: By the way, Hadoop has a REST API already called WebHDFS, so if you're just trying to upload/create files, I might start with that

Comment: yes, i have copied all the jars which gets downloaded as part maven to normal project to make it work but no luck :( bTW now i am moved to Maven project... could you please help me with webHDFS digest ?? anyway i will explore on google but in case any thing handy :)

Comment: BTW we have Rest api FW already enabled ... so i think moving to webHDFS would be tough.. as our FW is like querying table and giving results..

Comment: Have you tried searching elsewhere for what you're trying to do? https://shalishvj.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/java-hadoop-create-a-file-in-hdfs-programmatically-and-write-data-into-it/